# Test formatin condition in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to sum all the values from column where the cells have blue background.
How do I do that?

Here is what I tried:

```
=SUM(FILTER(color condition))
```

The only problem is that I do not know how to do `color condition`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Menu -> Tools -> Script gallery...
Search for `Sum by color`
Click Install and  Authorize and then Close

Go back to the spreadsheet

Then you have a function called

```
sumWhereBackgroundColorIs(color, rangeSpecification)
```

that should work.

There is a git for this on [github](https://github.com/clupascu/GoogleApps_SumByColor/blob/master/README.md#auto-updates) which auto-updates

Comment: oh no! oh well just trying to help

Comment: there's a git that has a similar function it can't be that deprecated https://github.com/clupascu/GoogleApps_SumByColor/blob/master/README.md#auto-updates

Comment: Yep, it is. Add ons is the new google thing. Then entire scripting system is changing.